How to "cut & paste" memory?
To "copy and paste" we use memcpy and memmove depending on whether the src and dest overlap, right?
Is there an encapsulated function for "cut and paste"?
If not, is there a relatively well-defined way to achieve that? Only way I can think of is to memset the redundant part to 0 after memmove.
To clarify by code, by mem_xxx, I want the array named arr to be "2345\0\0\0\0", instead of "234545\0\0" if use memmove.
char *arr = new char[8];
for ( int i = 2; i <= 5; i++ ) {
    arr[i] = char( i );
}
mem_xxx( arr, arr + 2, 5 - 2 + 1 ); 


Please note that the code you show isn't C, it's C++.

"Cut" and "paste" operations don't make sense at the abstraction level of raw memory. Cutting and pasting text shifts all text after that point left or right, to make room for pasted text or leave no gap when cutting text. You can't shift all memory "to the right" of some point left or right like that.

The closest C++ thing to the effects of a "combined cut-and-paste" might be std::rotate.

If you wanted to, you could write a memmovezap() which replaces the original byte with zero after copying it over. It is highly unclear why you would want that, but it's not hard to do.

Array indexes 6 and 7 will be uninitialized after your code.

@Atmo - it is not C code!! C tag is not valid

I got this question when I am trying to scratch a stack implementation mimicking std::deque, where the stl src code did a memory movement when either right or left end of the "map" still has a large unused proportion. Note the "map" is not std::map but an array of pointers to Tp, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a02018.html for details.

I would just memcpy the content and then use memset to zero out the region. Implementation of these functions are fast, copying words instead of bytes etc. I still don’t think that this is what you actually want to do, since there is no real point in setting the memory to 0.

You don't initialize all elements of the array, which means some values will be indeterminate. And in C++ using indeterminate values in any way leads to undefined behavior. Even copying these values to another location will use the values (otherwise they can't be copied).

@PkDrew: It sounds like you're trying to make a generic C++ container, when you say "mimicking std::deque". In that case, things like memmove are absolutely out of the question. You can't memmove a std::string for instance. You should know about std::move when writing such a container. That does include understanding std::move doesn't actually destroy the moved-from object.

@MSalters, many thanks for your reply, let me take this chance to further elaborate the background here. The toy is a pre-allocated array of pointers to the elements denoted as Tp, i.e., Tp *arr = new Tp[num_nodes];  Tricky part here is, instead of using the array from head, we use it from the middle, that way, for push_front(), you put it leftward, and rightward for push_back(). Now, if either end is reached, but a large portion of the other end is still free, in that case, the currently valid range is moved towards the spared end, hence this question.

@PkDrew: Note that none of the standard containers manage the contained objects via pointers. It's pretty bad for the locality of reference. And for a deque-like container, that is important. When it's less important, a std::list has a much cheaper push_front/push_back.

The STL library for C++ has a rotate function for this. Note that what you are asking about is simply the rotation of the elements in a given range.
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    char arr[8]{};//char* arr = new char[8];
    for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
        arr[i] = char(i);
    }
    // first middle   last
    //   |   |        | 
    //  [0 0 2 3 4 5] 0 0
    //  [2 3 4 5 0 0] 0 0
    std::rotate(arr, arr + 2, arr + 6);
}

If you are still interested in C, you can implement a similar function.
The illustration of the algorithm work:
0 0 2 3 4 5 0 0
2 0 0 3 4 5 0 0
2 3 0 0 4 5 0 0
2 3 4 0 0 5 0 0
2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0

Thanks for your answer mate, yes it would be what I am looking for which is an implementation hopefully introduced by the standard. True for my purpose what's needed is a rotation either leftward or rightward, and the array manipulated is maintained in a class internally with iterators, so I can mark the valid range.

Yes, it looks unusual. For example, the std::rotate(arr, arr + 4, arr + 6); command will return the arr to its previous state, i.e. move the elements to the right by 2 positions.
